# Android manifest properties

Tags: android, layout, android-manifest

I want to know what these properties mean in `android manifest`:: and why they are used

```
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"
            android:exported="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking, **[taskAffinity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff)** is the name of the task to which the application or activity wants to belong. See the docs for a somewhat more detailed explanation.

**[excludeFromRecents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude)** prevents the activity from appearing in the list of recent applications.

**configChanges** determines which configuration changes your activity is equipped to deal with. Handling configuration changes can be tricky, so this isn't encouraged. Most of the time, it's easier to let the system tear your app down and rebuild it when there's a configuration change.

**[exported](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported)** means that your activity can be called from other applications.

Answer (score 2):

1) `android:taskAffinity:`

The task that the activity has an affinity for. Activities with the same affinity conceptually belong to the same task (to the same "application" from the user's perspective). The affinity of a task is determined by the affinity of its root activity.

2) `android:excludeFromRecents:`

Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded from the list of recently used applications ("recent apps"). That is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent apps. "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".

3) `android:exported"`

Whether or not the activity can be launched by components of other applications — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. If "false", the activity can be launched only by components of the same application or applications with the same user ID.

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html